# Best Way to Store a UIImage in a Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiimage, nsdata

I'm pretty new to iOS development and the MVC concept but to my understanding, the model isn't supposed to have any UI related content. I have an image in my `images.xcassets` folder called `defaultImage` that I want to set as the default image for my class when it gets initialized. This class is part of my model and has the following public interface:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *imageData;

@end
```

The reason I store the image as `NSData` is because based on my assumption of the fact that UI isn't allowed in the model, I can't use a `UIImage` here. However I was unable to successfully initialize `imageData` to contain the data of the image. I tried the following:

```
#import "myClass.h"

@implementation myClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = @"No Name";
    self.imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"defaultImage"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Like I said though, `imageData` would contain `nil`. After looking around I found the following solution:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myClass.h" 

@implementation myClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = @"No Name";
        self.imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
        self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"]);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

So my question is, doesn't this break the rule of not allowing UI and UIKit inside the model? If not, please explain why not and if so, is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to have the image name or image path in the model and you can load the image wherever you need.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imageName;

@end
```

Worst case, if you have to have the data in the class itself, then use as below.

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = @"No Name";
        //self.imageData = [[NSData alloc] init]; //--Not required
        self.imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImage"]);
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: @llanchezhian, thank you for the help. Could you give me an example of why I would have to have the data in the class itself and also why it's better to have just the imageName in the model?

Comment: @bagelboy As I mentioned earlier, I strongly suggest to have just the imageName in the model, as it will cause problem (memory issues) if we have list of the classes. And also, iOS by default is having some cache techniques for loading images with `[UIImage imageNamed:]`